# console application output - how do I publish as a webservice 

Tags: c#, web-services, console-application

over the past 3 weeks - I have Built an xml file processing console application and it is working as planned.[Thanks to every on stack overflow for their inputs.]
The console application takes several XML files as input, checks for presence of certain data and produces a report on the console - with details of missing, mismatch information,in some cases gives out details of the hierarchical relationships in the data.

Next step I want to do with the application is, publish the result to a webservice - so that i can write a small web app to consume it.[not sure if that is possible]

right now the output is being written out to logfiles, excel file.

Request suggestions/ pointer to get me started in this direction.

[no specific reason to think about publishing to a webservice, all i want to do is pass the results out of the console and on to a browser - access anywhere and with rich UI]

Comment: Instead of thinking about this as "publishing to a web service" you might think of it as a web service that returns that latest publications of your console app (perhaps from the log files and excel file) in some xml format (or other format)

Comment: Read up on WCF Web Services and ask more detailed questions when you have problems. I learned a whole lot building this console application for hosting WCF services http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WCF/generic_wcf_host.aspx

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163647.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to create a web service to do that (although you could). Just put your code in a library whose output can be shown in the console application or on the web.